# WITH UNION ALL unable to use ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

When I am running

```
SELECT concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')  
FROM  occupations    
UNION ALL 
SELECT concat('There are total ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'.') 
FROM occupations 
GROUP BY occupation
```

the query is working fine but when I add order by

```
SELECT concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')  
FROM  occupations    
UNION ALL 
SELECT concat('There are total ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'.')  
FROM occupations 
GROUP BY occupation 
ORDER BY name
```

this is showing an error:

> Unknown column 'name' in 'order clause'

table occupations fields name,occupation

Comment: use alias for `name `

Comment: `concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')  as name`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')') as name
FROM  occupations    
UNION ALL 
SELECT concat('There are total ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'.') as name
FROM occupations GROUP BY occupation 
ORDER BY name
```

**Update: Why this is so:**
Because you don't have a common column named, `name`. When you apply a function to a query, mysql use a combination of that function name and parameters to create a column name for you. Which in reality means query will have a name of `concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')` (most probably upper cased) while the second will have `concat('There are total ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'.')`

It doesn't matter that the names are different as far as Union is concerned because mysql is smart enough to combine them together by their data type. However when you add an order by clause you need a column name that's common to both.

Answer (score 3):

Add alias for your select column:

```
SELECT CONCAT(name,'(', SUBSTRING(occupation,1,1),')') as name
FROM occupations
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(occupation),' ', occupation,'.') as name
FROM occupations
GROUP BY occupation
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')')  FROM  occupations    
UNION ALL SELECT concat('There are total ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'.') FROM occupations GROUP BY occupation 
ORDER BY name
```

there is no column named `name` being returned in the above query.

You can use this instead.

```
SELECT concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')') as name 
FROM  occupations    
UNION ALL 
SELECT concat('There are total ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'.') as name 
FROM occupations 
GROUP BY occupation 
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Relational data model relies on relational algebra. All your tables are relations. Selection is a clojure operation on your relations, that is, selection takes relation(s) as input and has relation as output.

That being said, let's identify the relations used in your question. Everything relies on your relation called `occupations`. You are doing two selections with that relation. The first outputs a record-based textual output, the second outputs a grouped value based on `operation`. Your `union` is not aware of names, as it contains a single, nameless column and that nameless column will not match the column you call `name`.

There is a technically sound solution provided by several answerers, but that answer is logically unsound. We should not give `name` as alias to the nameless column of the second selection, as it clearly is a number. You need to do something else, like this:

```
select total
from
(SELECT concat(name,'(',substring(occupation,1,1),')') as name, 0 as total
FROM  occupations    
UNION ALL 
SELECT name, concat('There are total ',count(occupation),' ', occupation,'.') as total
FROM occupations 
GROUP BY occupation) t
order by name
```